# Android - Make app login, case sensitive

Tags: java, android, rest, authentication, native

I am building a native Android app. I have a login page which is not case sensitive.

Example: both password's **Admin** and **admin** will allow the user to login. This should not be possible.

The login is working. My problem is making it case sensitive. I am still new to Java and Android, and not sure where to put the code to make it case sensitive.
Should i use equalsIgnoreCase()? 
If so, how would you use equalsIgnoreCase() in this login. Where do you compere the user login with the Rest API

Any help would be appropriated.

```
private class LoginProcess extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog_login.show();
    }

    String user = userInput.getText().toString();
    String pass = passInput.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        String address = my_url + "api/user/login.json";

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        String requestBody;
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", user);
        params.put("password", pass);

        Iterator entries = params.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
            builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
            entries.remove();
        }
        requestBody = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(address);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "utf-8"));
            writer.write(requestBody);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            InputStream inputStream;
            // get stream
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                Log.w("URL", "Ok");
            } else {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
                Log.w("URL", "Bad request");
            }

            // parse stream
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String temp, response = "";
            while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response += temp;
            }
            // put into JSONObject
            jsonObject.put("Content", response);
            jsonObject.put("Message", urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
            jsonObject.put("Length", urlConnection.getContentLength());
            jsonObject.put("Type", urlConnection.getContentType());

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
            session_name = jsonObj.getString("session_name");
            session_id = jsonObj.getString("sessid");
            token = jsonObj.getString("token");

            return jsonObject.toString();

        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            return e.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any checks regarding the password, so I'm not sure whether this is an Android/Java problem.

Comment: Dont you think the issue is at server side?

Comment: I think you are right. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use Basic Auth System for your login logic. This should send you back a token you will use for others API calls.
Take a look at Retrofit and OkHttpClient.
Also, all your network connectivity logic should be in another class.

And in your case, case sensitiveness must be tested on the server side.
Your android application must be oblivious about the credentials validity. It just takes it from the user and gives it to the server API which validates (or not)

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.